# React to manual cookies change on browser

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, web-frontend

I'm developing a client-side only React application and I would like to know how a given component to re-render after I manually change a cookie on the browser application tab.
I don't want to use an external package (like react-cookie).

ATM I have this:

```
  const [cookieValue, setCookieValue] = useState<number>(
    parseInt(
      document.cookie
        .split('; ')
        .find((row) => row.startsWith('test='))
        ?.split('=')[1] ?? '0'
    )
  );

document.cookie = 'test=2; expires=Thu, 18 Dec 2022 12:00:00 UTC';
```

And inside an useEffect I don't exactly know what to put so that I can update the cookieValue variable with the value I'm setting on the browser.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to do this natively. If you're setting the cookie in your component I would recommend tracking the value in state and setting it to `document.cookie` in an effect. Otherwise you'll need to manually poll for changes or use an external package.